# Generating map thumbnails using OpenStreetMap

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I'm a relative newcomer to [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and am wondering if anyone has any experience in generating map thumbnails from the image tiles for a given latitude and longitude? As an example Sydney, Australia can be found at `lat. 33.8683` and `long. 151.2086`. I want to be able to generate a 128x128 png from the image tiles for those coordinates at a particular zoom level.

I've used `ArcGIS` before and it has a dedicated service for such a task. I've Googled quite a bit and not found anything as yet for `OpenStreetMap`.

I'm using Java so would probably want to deploy such capability as a web service.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I should add that I'm running my own tile server which I built using the instructions at [switch2osm.org](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out after discovering how `OpenStreetMap` stores its tiles. The basics are:

- Tiles are 256 × 256 pixel PNG files
- Each zoom level is a directory, each column is a subdirectory, and each tile in that column is a file
- To access a file use `http://localhost/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`
- Calculate the `${z} ${x} and ${y}` values based on the latitude and longitude.

There is some excellent documentation on this subject on the [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), including code blocks in various languages to calculate the tile names. I needed a Java solution so the code I ended up using is:

```
public class Mapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int zoom = 11;
        double lat = -33.77651d;
        double lon = 150.94712d;
        System.out.println("http://localhost/osm/"
            + getTileNumber(lat, lon, zoom) + ".png");
    }

    public static String getTileNumber(double lat, double lon, int zoom)
    {
        int xtile = (int)Math.floor((lon + 180) / 360 * (1<<zoom));
        int ytile = (int)Math.floor((1 - Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(lat))
            + 1 / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat))) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1<<zoom));
        return ("" + zoom + "/" + xtile + "/" + ytile);
    }
}
```

This returns a URL for the required image tile, eg: `http://localhost/osm/11/1882/1228.png` which you can then use to acquire the image. I then used [Thumbnailator](https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) to generate the 128x128 thumbnail size:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("tile.png"))
  .size(128, 128)
  .toFile(new File("thumbnail.png"));
```

Happy days.

Comment: It will find the tile, but how you deal with fact that coordinates may be very close to border?